# How to sort an assocoative array in php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sorting

I want to sort this array based on count in descending order. here is my `array`

```
array(   
   46 => 
      array (
       'name' => 'HSR Layout',
       'url' => 'hsr-layout',
       'count' => 2,
      ),

   37 => 
      array (
       'name' => 'Electronic City',
       'url' => 'electronic-city',
       'count' => 3,
      )
  )
```

Comment: At-least search once on google:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you are using Laravel, which your tag suggests, you can use collections to manipulate arrays like this. For example:

```
$array = collect($array)->sortBy('count')->reverse()->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks @Jerodev. I am using laravel. It works :)

Comment: amazing thank you so much!

Comment: The the best answer ever, thank you so much

Comment: It Works great, and if I want to be order by month ? how it would be ?

Answer (score 5):

Using `array_multisort()`.

```
$array = array(   
   46 => 
      array (
       'name' => 'HSR Layout',
       'url' => 'hsr-layout',
       'count' => 2,
      ),

   37 => 
      array (
       'name' => 'Electronic City',
       'url' => 'electronic-city',
       'count' => 3,
      )
  );

$price = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $row)
{
    $count[$key] = $row['count'];
}
array_multisort($count, SORT_DESC, $array);

print_r($array);
```

**Program Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Electronic City
            [url] => electronic-city
            [count] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => HSR Layout
            [url] => hsr-layout
            [count] => 2
        )

)
```

**Live demo : [Click Here](https://eval.in/598206)**

Comment: check above code its useful to you for your issue. @Vikash

Comment: This is much too complicated, a simple `usort` with a `count` comparing lambda-function is all that's needed here

Comment: @RuchishParikh  as OP says he is using laravel your answer is not useful for him. Also a complex answer is not needed if you want to give it too also:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value

Comment: ok i will keep in mind. Thanks for your advice @Anant